# Can I use Knockout.js-External-Template-Engine with nested models?

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to implement **Knockout.js-External-Template-Engine** using a working demo of nested templates

Currently I have a setup like so

```
<ul data-bind="template: {name: 'TopTemplate'}"></ul>

<script type="text/html" id="TopTemplate">
    <li><span>Result</span>
        <ul data-bind=" template: {name:  'FooTemplate' , foreach: foos}">
        </ul>
    </li>
    <button data-bind='click: addFoo'>Add Foo</button>
</script>
```

When I try to move this TopTemplate to a file (templates\view.html),  **view.html** ie

```
<li><span>Result</span>
<ul data-bind=" template: {name:  'FooTemplate' , foreach: foos} " style="list-style-type:circle;margin-left:15px">
</ul>
</li>
<button data-bind='click: addFoo'>Add Foo</button>
```

fails **( unable to parse bindings....foos is not defined )**

here's my view model updated with the **whichTemplateToUse**

```
  var viewModel = {
    isEditable: ko.observable(false),
    foos: ko.mapping.fromJS([]),
    loadInitialData: function () {
        ko.mapping.fromJS(serverData, dataMappingOptions, viewModel.foos);
    },
    loadUpdatedData: function () {
        ko.mapping.fromJS(serverData, dataMappingOptions, viewModel.foos);
    },
    whichTemplateToUse: function() {
        return viewModel.isEditable() ? 'edit' : 'view';
    }
};
```

I'm sure I've missed the point here - but do I need to change my Top Template data-bind expression

to allow the loading of an external sub template. The top template works with simple static text so I think the basic integration is correct.

thanks!

Comment: not sure if many people use that old templating style anymore,  the newer versions of knockout has much more elegant ways of doing things

Comment: @Keith do you have an example you can provide?

Comment: the answer is yes - http://ifandelse.com/?p=100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found a good [demo](http://ifandelse.com/?p=100) which does this exact thing.

Comment: Your HTML is wrong as well, you have your <li> surrounding your <ul> tags. It should be the reverse, like in the demo :)